# How tall would a tower at the South Pole have to be for the top to get year-around sunshine?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How tall would a tower at the South Pole have to be for the top to get year-around sunshine?

No doubt the height would vary each year since the [Tropic of Cancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropic_of_Cancer) changes latitude slightly. Perhaps assume 23.5° N for calculation's sake.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

assuming spherical earth with radius $R$ and axis tilt $\mu$, from geometry reasoning we get:
$$
\frac{R}{R+h}=\cos \mu \Rightarrow R\left( \frac{1}{\cos \mu}  - 1 \right)=h
$$
[image: earth]

so your tower height should be $h=((1/\cos(23.5)-1)\cdot 6371 \text{ km} = 576.2 \text{ km}$; greetings to [ISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_atmosphere)

for ellipsoid-Earth the height is bit different, but the above is a fine estimate

Comment: +1 for drawing the south pole at the top of the image contrary to arbitrary convention ;-)

Comment: "greetings to ISS" - I missed this at first reading... :D

Comment: lol, yeah, I probably put myself too much in the Antarctic...